# wicket urls - wicket wont display the get url

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I am using wicket in my web application. 
Assuming I have pages a b c where I move from A to B using page parameters change somthing in page B model using ajax and B to C (without using page params).

problem :
The scenario is moving A->B->C while changing page b model and pressing the back button 
B<-C
beacuse when page B instance (B1)was generated I used get parameters , therefore a new page B instance was  generated(B2) I would like to return every time to page B

is there a wicket style solution to this problem ?

thank u for getting this far in my post :).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get your post, you would like to return to page B with the model that you got at B1?

The issue you should solve is how the model is persisted in Page B. If you create a new model from the `PageParameters` (I guess that is what you have as your Page gets 'recreated') you will loose the ajax changes. I think you should persist your model changes somewhere and reload them (for example a `LoadableDetachableModel`)

Comment: i dont need to persist a thing there's an instance in the system with this model attaced to it , the problem this instance is not markd in the wicket system like in http://host:8080/appName/?5 so 5 is this page numbrt . how to achive it ?

Comment: I think you cannot know for sure if this instance is still anywhere. AFAIK pages are serialized after they are rendered, and this store can be clean/empied/etc. (see here: http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/versioningCaching.html) If you do not persist your values somehow (does not need to be a database, it can be somewhere memory as well), you might lose them.

Comment: it does work when A is wicket so this page instance is stores somewhere, it might be due to the reason no pageId is available . but it's stored .